# c# Compilation Error

Tags: c#

I'm doing image steganography and visual cryptography project using RSA algorithm. While compiling the project I'm getting these errors:

> ArgumentException was unhandled

and also

> Empty path name is not legal

This error shown in:

```
FileStream outStream = 
    new FileStream(stegoFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create and open a file, but you are not specifying a name for the file. This is not possible, so the function complains by throwing an exception.

To fix this, put the name of the file that you want to open into `stegoFileName`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this article and certainly the possible exceptions: [**MSDN: FileStream Constructor**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyhc0kft.aspx). You get the *ArgumentException* for following possible reasons:

> path is an empty string (""), contains only white space, or contains one or more invalid characters.

So make sure the path (the value of 'stegoFileName') is not *null*, not empty, does not contain invalid characters and refers to a valid path.